# ethereum-bridge oracle on private network does not receive queries

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, oracles

I have a private network with a few nodes and I have installed ethereum-bridge to deploy an Oracle.

One of my blockchain nodes is used by ethereum-bridge to deploy the oracle. The node is started with the command
`geth.exe --identity "7"  --datadir "D:\Blockchain\1" --networkid 4999 --rpc --rpcport 47000 --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,shh,personal" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --port 30800 --nodiscover  --shh --ipcdisable console`

while `ethereum-bridge`:

`ethereum-bridge -H localhost:47000 -a 0`

These are the logs on the `ethereum-bridge` console

```
[2019-02-21T09:45:14.820Z] INFO you are running ethereum-bridge - version: 0.6.1
[2019-02-21T09:45:14.821Z] INFO saving logs to: ./bridge.log
[2019-02-21T09:45:14.822Z] INFO using active mode
[2019-02-21T09:45:14.823Z] INFO Connecting to eth node http://localhost:47000
[2019-02-21T09:45:16.101Z] INFO connected to node type Geth/7/v1.8.21-stable-9dc5d1a9/windows-amd64/go1.11.4
[2019-02-21T09:45:16.588Z] WARN Using 0x8668dc605fe8d721dbb96378fd8155c621bea37d to query contracts on your blockchain, make sure it is unlocked and do not use the same address to deploy your contracts
[2019-02-21T09:45:16.711Z] INFO deploying the oraclize connector contract...
[2019-02-21T09:45:26.998Z] INFO connector deployed to: 0x251deddf98aca280a252d9e5f7b1b246bc3f66f7
[2019-02-21T09:45:27.119Z] WARN deterministic OAR disabled/not available, please update your contract with the new custom address generated
[2019-02-21T09:45:27.120Z] INFO deploying the address resolver contract...
[2019-02-21T09:45:37.534Z] INFO address resolver (OAR) deployed to: 0xb69156280a1461003a079387c2b5b827b3f0fc53
[2019-02-21T09:45:37.535Z] INFO updating connector pricing...
[2019-02-21T09:45:47.861Z] INFO successfully deployed all contracts
[2019-02-21T09:45:47.871Z] INFO instance configuration file saved to D:\GitHub\ethereum-bridge\config\instance\oracle_instance_20190221T094547.json

Please add this line to your contract constructor:

OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0xB69156280a1461003a079387c2B5B827B3f0fc53);

[2019-02-21T09:45:47.996Z] INFO Listening @ 0x251deddf98aca280a252d9e5f7b1b246bc3f66f7 (Oraclize Connector)

(Ctrl+C to exit)
```

Then, using a different blockchain node I have deployed the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.4;

import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract WolframAlpha is usingOraclize {

    uint256 public beginningPastQuarter;
    uint256 public beginningCurrentQuarter;
    uint256 public payoutIntervalSeconds;

    event newOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event newTimestampMeasure(uint256 timestamp);

     constructor() public {
        payoutIntervalSeconds = 120;
        beginningPastQuarter = 0;
        beginningCurrentQuarter = 0;
        OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0xB69156280a1461003a079387c2B5B827B3f0fc53);
    }

    function stringToUint(string memory s) internal pure returns (uint) {
        bytes memory b = bytes(s);
        uint result = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { 
            if (uint8(b[i]) >= 48 && uint8(b[i]) <= 57) {
                result = result * 10 + (uint8(b[i]) - 48); 
            }
        }
        return result; 
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string memory result) public {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();

        uint256 t = stringToUint(result);
        if (t-beginningCurrentQuarter >= payoutIntervalSeconds){
            beginningPastQuarter = beginningCurrentQuarter;
            beginningCurrentQuarter = t;
        }

        emit newTimestampMeasure(t);
    }

    function getUTCTimestamp(uint256 delay) public payable {
        emit newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
        oraclize_query(delay,"WolframAlpha", "Timestamp now");
    }

    function pay(address receiver) public payable{
        address(uint160(receiver)).send(msg.value);
    }

    function balance(address a) public returns(uint256 r){
        return a.balance;
    }
}
```

After deploying the contract, I have sent some ether to it so it can pay for the calls to the Oracle.

Now if I try to use the oracle by calling `contractInstance.getUTCTimestamp(0,{from:eth.accounts[0],value:2222222,gas:5000000});` the transaction is mined but nothing happens in the `ethereum-bridge` console.

If I inspect the transaction and its receipts I get:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x1c2d77b1e07d51894fdf0e2c3423d01538149d657b89e2568b5846d049452fda",
  blockNumber: 5799,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 5000000,
  from: "0xed2632f90f57dbbeb8e1d27277f4ef85a42851d2",
  gasUsed: 5000000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x67de497db6efcd76b0f4aba9255cd7744430eb7aded05e86090952071c53e97a",
  to: "0x217e753369532055c55c3588774275b8a58d5cf4",
  transactionHash: "0x21fb0191b15e748f93e9884349f8066cd765c0948d8050d99ebe99d32eb9543b",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

```
{
  blockHash: "0x1c2d77b1e07d51894fdf0e2c3423d01538149d657b89e2568b5846d049452fda",
  blockNumber: 5799,
  from: "0xed2632f90f57dbbeb8e1d27277f4ef85a42851d2",
  gas: 5000000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x21fb0191b15e748f93e9884349f8066cd765c0948d8050d99ebe99d32eb9543b",
  input: "0xa01569d70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: 1048,
  r: "0x782a4d75ca59f5f0646733653474c6a42e26001513996c86635be1394d23d1c2",
  s: "0x23a1346876b104f527e291f885bfb21fe406b17128a18ddb7167bdf8ce021555",
  to: "0x217e753369532055c55c3588774275b8a58d5cf4",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x41",
  value: 2222222
}
```

It seems to me that the transaction is using all gas and that happens even if I increase the gas value. The weird thing is that if I test this contract in remix the total gas used is below 200000. What could be the problem?

Comment: What address are you deploying the Oraclize-using contract with?

Comment: I am using a different node so Oracle is on one address and  Oraclize-using contract on another one

Comment: W.r.t the address used to deploy the transaction, the node is irrelevant. What address did you deploy with?

Comment: The Oracle contracs used the address `0x8668dc605fe8d721dbb96378fd8155c621bea37d` while the  Oraclize-using ones `0xed2632f90f57dbbeb8e1d27277f4ef85a42851d2`

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem,after 3 days and a day morning and thanks to the help from @D-Nice @gskapka , I finally solved the problem.I need to put my thoughts together to help guys who may encounter the same problem.
- only support the `dev` geth private network
I am sorry to say that the oraclize(ethereum-bridge) is only supported the `dev`chain , which means you should start your private network using geth like

```
geth --networkid 15 --datadir ./data --rpc --rpcapi "admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,txpool,web3" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --dev
```

or simply, you can start you your private network using

```
geth --dev --rpc console
```

- if you deploy the contract using ethereum-bridge on `Non-dev` private network, you will get gas error like

```
gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction in private network
```

so, all the problem is caused by `Non-dev`private network!
Good luck for you!